# iPhone - Zoom in During Startup

Tags: iphone, sdk, transition

I'm not sure why, but my app does not have the zoom in animation that all iPhone apps have when they start up. The screen, which is black, zooms in and then it just cuts to the actual view. It doesn't zoom in the actual view. Is there an option that I'm missing in an implementation file or in the Interface Builder?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting a file named "Default.png" with size 320x480 in your resources folder.
I believe this is also in the info.plist file if you need it to be called something different.

The SDK will find it and use it as a splash-screen until your app is loaded.

Hope this was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As RickiG suggested you can place a Default.png within the resources folder. For landscape simply swap the dimensions.

Portrait = 320x480
Landscape = 480x320